# Не работает шорткод в php функции

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Не работает шорткод в php функции. В чем ошибка?

```
function custom_call_for_price() {
    return '
    <a href="#contact_form_pop" class="fancybox">Contact Us</a>
    <div style="display:none" class="fancybox-hidden">
    <div id="contact_form_pop">
        [contact-form-7 id="5" title="Контактная форма 1"]
    </div>
    </div>
    ';
}
```

всплывающее окно открывается, но в нём написано: `[contact-form-7 id="5" title="Контактная форма 1"]`, а хотелось бы что бы форма открывалась

Comment: вордпресс? ну так функция возвращает одно, а это надо еще обработать.

Comment: А откуда, говорите, там должна взяться эта форма? Или вы какую-то CMS используете?

Comment: Вордпресс. Это всё реализуется при помощи двух плагинов: Easy FancyBox (модальное окно) и Contact Form 7 (сама форма).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В документации к этому плагину рекомендуется использовать метод `do_shortcode`. Поэтому код должен выглядеть вот так:

```
function custom_call_for_price() 
{return '<a href="#contact_form_pop" class="fancybox">Contact Us</a>
<div style="display:none" class="fancybox-hidden"><div id="contact_form_pop">' . do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="5" title="Контактная форма 1"]') . '</div></div>';}
```

Comment: Ой спасибо тебе, добрый человек. Всё получилось.